# language-pack-uk-base error

Tags: updates

I got error when updating elementary juno

```
rytsar@rytsar-laptop:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox3 sox ubuntu-minimal
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/372 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4.096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'language-pack-uk-base': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your dpkg (package manager) can't read the listing file, required to install the 'language-pack-uk-base' package because of input/output error. Possible cause:
file system corruption. You can try solutions suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2), or check your unmounted system partition with [`fsck`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/fsck.htm) from a bootable USB drive.